# scrapy with ::before Selector

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

```
<div class="priceContainerDescuentoPG">
    <p class="priceDescuentoPG">
      ::before
      "$29.610"
    </p>
</div>
```

You tried to extract this price with scrapy using this xpath the result is empty.

```
//*[@class="priceDescuentoPG"]/text()
```

I'm sure the problem is the :: before Selector. How can I solve and skip this selector? Thanks for the help

Comment: You should update your post with the elements visible in the image so that it is possible to work on it. Thanks.

Comment: What is the command you use to extract? I get `['\n      ::before\n      "$29.610"\n    ']` when extracting with xpath you mentioned.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding, I do the test in scrapy shell https://www.pepeganga.com/offers with this command response.xpath ('// * [@ class = "priceDescuentoPG"] / text ()'), the result is [ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happen because the value of **priceDescuentoPG** is calculated using a function on [general.js](https://pepeganga.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/general.js) line 117:

```
var descuentoTargetaPGVitrinas = function(){

    $('.vitrineHome ul .midLevel').each(function(){
        var precioVigente = $(this).find('.priceProd').text().replace("$","").replace(/,/g,"").replace(/\./g,"");
        var descuentoPG = (precioVigente*0.90);
        $(this).find('.priceDescuentoPG').text('$' + formatearMoneda(descuentoPG/100,0,'.',','));
    });
};
```

You can copy this function inside your spider:

```
prices = response.xpath("//*[@class='priceProd']/text()").extract()

for price in prices:
  price_prod = price.strip().replace('$', '').replace(',','').replace('.', '')
  descuento_pg = float(price_prod) * 0.90
```

Comment: You just gave me a master class, thank you teacher resolved. :) These are the answers that are worth GOLD